# Reading in Excel (downloaded with automated script) produces error when not manually opened and saved first

Tags: r, excel

I run an automated script to download 3 .xls files from 3 websites every hour. When I later try to read in the .xls files in R to further work with them, R produces the following error message:

"***Error: IOException (Java): block[ 2 ] already removed - does your POIFS have circular or duplicate block references?***"

When I manually open and save the .xls files this problem doesn't appear anymore and everything works normal, but since the total number of files is increasing with 72 every day this is not a nice work around.

The script I use to download and save the files:

```
library(httr)

setwd("WORKDIRECTION")
orig_wd <- getwd()
FOLDERS <- c("NAME1","NAME2","NAME3")        #representing folder names
LINKS <- c("WEBSITE_1",                      #the urls from which I download
"WEBSITE_2",
"WEBSITE_3")
NO <- length(FOLDERS)

for(i in 1:NO){
 today <- as.character(Sys.Date())
 if (!file.exists(paste(FOLDERS[i],today,sep="/"))){
  dir.create(paste(FOLDERS[i],today,sep="/"))
 }
 setwd(paste(orig_wd,FOLDERS[i],today,sep="/"))
 dat<-GET(LINKS[i])
 bin <- content(dat,"raw")
 now <- as.character(format(Sys.time(),"%X"))
 now <- gsub(":",".",now)
 writeBin(bin,paste(now,".xls",sep=""))
 setwd(orig_wd) 
}
```

I then read in the files with the following script:

```
require(gdata)
require(XLConnect)
require(xlsReadWrite)
wb = loadWorkbook("FILEPATH")
df = readWorksheet(wb, "Favourite List" , header = FALSE)
```

Does anybody have experience with this type of error, and knows a solution or workaround?

Comment: Side note: [list.files()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html) would make your code a lot prettier.

Comment: The solution was to read in the file using the readxl package using df=read_excel("Path")

Comment: Add your solution with more details as an `Answer` below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is partly resolved by using the readxl package available in the CRAN library. After installation files can be read in with:

```
library(readxl) 
read_excel("PathToFile")
```

The only problem is, that the last column is omitted while reading in. If I find a solution for this I'll update the awnser.